# Are Triceratops and Eotriceratops similar enough to be considered as the same genus?

Tags: taxonomy, palaeontology, dinosaurs

Everybody knows *Triceratops*, the horned dinosaur from Late Cretaceous North America, who lived 68-66 MYA.

In 2007, *Eotriceratops xerinsularis* was named and described ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eotriceratops)). It lived in (what is now) Canada about 68 MYA. It is a little bigger than *Triceratops* but in many aspect very similar, e.g. they both have long horns and solid frill, and postcranial skeleton. Gregory S. Paul, in his *Princton Field Guide to Dinosaurs* 2016, suggested putting *Eotriceratops xerinsularis* in the same genus as *Triceratops*, renaming it to *Triceratops xerinsularis*. I find this suggestion appealing, but I know Paul's taxonomy is unorthodox and not mainstream (e.g. I do not agree with the thesis that *Torosaurus* is merely a full adult *Triceratops*).

So the question is: can *Eotriceratops xerinsularis* be put in the same genus as *Triceratops* and is this suggestion is plausiable enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taxonomists have wide leeway over assigning higher taxa. The publication process in which *Eotriceratops* was described as a new genus made it a new genus. However, given a different set of reviewers, they may have rejected the new generic description, and suggested that the author put it into *Triceratops*. The process is somewhat arbitrary, and there are some random elements to higher taxon assignment. But it is the system we use. If somebody were to write a paper to synonomize *Eotriceratops* with *Triceratops*, and that paper were accepted, then *Eotriceratops* would cease to be a valid name. Its all about publication precedence. Gregory  Paul may have good reason for his suggestion, but it must be published before a change is made.

Comment: Not sure if relevant to this exact species but a VERY good talk about how & why we have so many different potentially worng) dinosaur species: https://www.ted.com/talks/jack_horner_shape_shifting_dinosaurs

Comment: Can you add references?

Answer (score -1):

Eotriceratops was a larger species of triceratops so they both were similar in name but different in size
Well eotriceratops was a larger ceratopsid but both of them had different predators for example the triceratops horridus was hunted by the T-Rex but for the eotriceratops I don't what predators it had

Comment: Welcome. We expect answers to be clear and complete, without personal opinions. Importantly we ask answers to be supported by citations, preferably journal papers.